# Avoid 2d for loop and make the computation faster

Tags: r

Consider the example

```
m=1000
x=seq(0,1,length.out=m)
y=seq(0,1,length.out=m)
d=runif(500)
```

Would like to compute f(x,y)=sum(exp(x-d)*exp(y-d)).

I am using

```
f=array(0,dim=c(m,m))
for (i in 1:m){
 for (j in 1:m){
   f[i,j]=sum(exp(x[i]-d)*exp(y[j]-d))
   }
  }
```

Computation of f is too much time consuming as it running two for-loop.

Is there any faster way to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got correctly what you are trying to do, you can arrive to your desired result through:

```
f2<-sum(exp(-2*d))*exp(outer(x,y,"+"))
#check the result
all.equal(f,f2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working fine. I just stuck when I use this technique for  f(x,y)=sum((exp(x-d)^2)*(exp(y-d)^2)). Then using outer function is not straight forward. Could you please suggest how to deal with using outer function?

Comment: Just use simple algebra to get outside the sum what doesn't depend on `d`. Also, I think that you want `exp((x-d)^2)` rather than `exp(x-d)^2` (see the difference?).